Have any football team came from a 5-0 or 5 goal deficit in first leg to win on second leg?
I have been looking for bigger comeback than PSG vs Barcelona in 2017 i.e La Remontada in which Barca beat PSG in second leg. Artmedia Bratislava vs Celtic was close as they lost 5-0 in first leg but Celtic could get only 4.
I have found couple of examples but all were 4 goal

Real Madrid vs Borussia Mönchengladbach, 1985-86 UEFA Cup
Partizan Belgrade vs QPR, 1984-85 UEFA Cup
Leixões SC vs  FC La Chaux-de-Fonds,1961/62 UEFA Cup
CONMEBOL 1995 cup final between Rosario Central vs Atletico Mineiro

It has not happened in Europe maybe it has happened in other continents. Can anyone find a match where a team came from a 5 goal deficit to win in second leg(playoff,tiebreaker,any).

I found another one
Shkëndija vs The New Saints  2018

I FOUND ONE FC Lustenau vsSV Urfahr 1912  .https://www.transfermarkt.co.in/rapid-lustenau_sv-urfahr-1912/vorbericht/spielbericht/4021371

If you've found an answer, you should be able to post it as an answer yourself. (I'll note, however, that in both of the ones you've mentioned in the comments so far, the teams only came back from four-goal deficits.)
